# ruby on rails and vuex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to output data from vuex but I get an error. (syntax error).

**ruby:**

```
- if {{ $store.state.filter.totalParts = 0}}
   .flow-control__items-count #{number_with_delimiter(@total_parts)} шт.
- else 
   | {{ $store.state.filter.totalParts }}
```

Need to output data from vuex when totalParts > 1.
What needs to be changed?

Comment: Ruby renders templates server side, vuex runs clientside, you can't access vuex data from the server, it's not how it works

Comment: @arieljuod Ah... thx